# Default camel case of property names in JSON serialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net, camelcasing

I have a bunch of classes that will be serialized to JSON at some point and for the sake of following both C# conventions on the back-end and JavaScript conventions on the front-end, I've been defining properties like this:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="myFoo")]
public int MyFoo { get; set; }
```

So that in C# I can:

```
MyFoo = 10;
```

And in Javascript I can:

```
if (myFoo === 10)
```

But doing this for every property is tedious. Is there a quick and easy way to set the default way JSON.Net handles property names so it will automatically camel case unless told otherwise?

Answer (score 42):

You can use the provided class [Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm):

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
var jobj = JObject.FromObject(request, serializer);
```

In other words, you don't have to create a custom resolver yourself.

Comment: `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` has actually been around for a long time.  It was present at least as far back as [Json.Net 4.0.2](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/4.0.2) (released Apr 21, 2011).  If you notice, the OP's resolver even inherits from it.

Comment: By OP I assume you mean the person who asked the question. There's no mention of it there. Good catch though.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the resolver as an attribute of the class?

Answer (score 19):

When serializing your object, pass in some custom settings.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, settings);
```

Comment: Not sure how this is really much different than @DaveKennedy's answer.

Comment: Look at the TWO differences. a) `JsonSerializer` vs `JsonSerializerSettings` and then b) `JsonConvert.XX` vs `JObject.XX`.

Comment: The point of the question is `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`, everything else is secondary.

Comment: still useful to see where ContractResolvers can be used.

Answer (score 10):

Better to use the new [`CamelCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm) (since [9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/9.0.1)):

```
new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
       NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
    }
};
```

It does not override custom names set by attribute `JsonProperty("Name")` by default. (You can change the behaviour by `CamelCaseNamingStrategy(bool, bool)` ctor.) So, does not need to create custom class like @Matt Burland's answer.

Comment: Do you happen to know which is the first Newtonsoft.Json version to contain CamelCaseNamingStrategy?

Comment: @vezenkov since [9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/9.0.1) according to the changelog.

Answer (score 9):

`JObject.FromObject` uses default settings from `JsonConvert` defaults.
There is a func property that you can assign like this:

```
 JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
 {
   ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
 };
```

and whenever you call `Jobject.FromObject`, it will use this func to construct settings.

Answer (score 7):

Since the accepted answer is link-only, I'm adding the actual code I ended up using (in case the link dies). It's largely the same as what was in the link:

```
// Automatic camel casing because I'm bored of putting [JsonProperty] on everything
// See: http://harald-muehlhoff.de/post/2013/05/10/Automatic-camelCase-naming-with-JsonNET-and-Microsoft-Web-API.aspx#.Uv43fvldWCl
public class CamelCase : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member,
        MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var res = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        var attrs = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), true);

        if (attrs.Any())
        {
            var attr = (attrs[0] as JsonPropertyAttribute);
            if (res.PropertyName != null && attr.PropertyName != null)
                res.PropertyName = attr.PropertyName;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

The only change I made was the addition of `attr.PropertyName != null` to the if clause because of the case where I had added something like:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

And didn't want to specify the `PropertyName` (so it's null). The above will be serialized in JSON as `someProperty`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a custom [contract resolver](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html):

```
class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            property.PropertyName = char.ToLower(property.PropertyName[0]) + string.Join("", property.PropertyName.Skip(1));
        }

        return properties;
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyClass(), 
                Formatting.Indented, 
                new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver() });
```

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 5.0 you can use System.Text.Json and specifiy the ProperyNamingPolicy inside the JsonSerializerOptions

> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties#use-camel-case-for-all-json-property-names) a link to the Microsoft docs page on setting the property to use camel case.

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    WriteIndented = true
};
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast, serializeOptions);
```

Class

```
public class WeatherForecastWithPropertyNameAttribute
{
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("Wind")]
    public int WindSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

JSON output

```
{
  "date": "2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00",
  "temperatureCelsius": 25,
  "summary": "Hot",
  "Wind": 35
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static JsonSerializer FormattingData()
{
   var jsonSerializersettings = new JsonSerializer {
   ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
   return jsonSerializersettings;
}


public static JObject CamelCaseData(JObject jObject) 
{   
     var expandoConverter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
     dynamic camelCaseData = 
     JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jObject.ToString(), 
     expandoConverter); 
     return JObject.FromObject(camelCaseData, FormattingData());
}
```

Comment: Expand object helps to resolve to convert the Pascalcase to CamelCase