# How to force camel case in C# .NET structured logging?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, nlog, structured-logging

Does anyone know how to change the behavior/format of the structured logging in .NET Core C# to be camel case (ex: camelCase)?  I'm trying to leverage structured logging like as follows:

```
Logger.LogInformation("Some text here. My object: {@some_class}", someClass);
```

Let's say some class looks like as follows:

```
class SomeClass {
  [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "intField")] // this does NOT work for structured logging
  int IntField {get;set;}
  string StrField {get;set;}
}
```

For the sake of brevity, I'll receive some output like follows:

```
{
  ...
  "message": "Some text here. My object: {\"IntField\":5,\"StrField\":\"I'm here\"}",
  "some_class": {
    "IntField":5,
    "StrField":"I'm here"
  },
  ...
}
```

But what I want is for all the fields to be camel case like all the parent fields in the log are.  The following is the desired outcome:

```
{
  ...
  "message": "Some text here. My object: {\"IntField\":5,\"StrField\":\"I'm here\"}",
  "some_class": {
    "intField":5,
    "strField":"I'm here"
  },
  ...
}
```

I've tried setting up my JsonConvert.DefaultSettings with a new JsonSerializerSettings object to force camel casing, but I'm assuming this only works if I'm actually serializing to string ([got this from StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783137/default-camel-case-of-property-names-in-json-serialization)).  To which I'm guessing the logger does not use under the hood.

If it helps I'm using I am using .NET Core 2.2 and v4.8.1.

Comment: You can change to JSON.NET: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#i-like-to-use-jsonnet-for-creating-json and configure the JSON.NET serializer-settings to be camel-case.

Comment: Awesome, this worked, but luckily I caught an adverse side effect. In another part of code, I was using a lazy logger to log a LogEventInfo with properties that was logging an exception which created an infinite loop in the logger (well long enough where I had to kill it).  Now I have to, ToString() my exception.  I didn't see an easy way to address this through the serializer settings.

Comment: Should be handled with JSON.NET `ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`. You can also register special types to be ignored by JSON.NET if logging Entity-Framework-Exceptions

Comment: Hmmm, I have that.  Maybe its not a reference loop, but the exception is just super deep in its property tree looking like this --> exception.targetSite.module.assembly.customAttributes[].constructor.module.assembly... 
Also, thank you for your help.

Comment: Exception.TargetSite should be excluded with Json.Net 12.0.3. See also https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/1897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create your **custom serializer** with `CamelCaseNamingStrategy` as NamingStrategy config.

```cs
    internal class JsonNetSerializer : NLog.IJsonConverter
    {
        private readonly DefaultContractResolver contractResolver;

        public JsonNetSerializer()
        {
            contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
            {
                // KEY CONFIG !!!
                NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
            };
        }

        /// <summary>Serialization of an object into JSON format.</summary>
        /// <param name="value">The object to serialize to JSON.</param>
        /// <param name="builder">Output destination.</param>
        /// <returns>Serialize succeeded (true/false)</returns>
        public bool SerializeObject(object value, StringBuilder builder)
        {
            try
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = contractResolver
                });

                builder.Append(json);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                NLog.Common.InternalLogger.Error(e, "Error when custom JSON serialization");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

2) **Change default** for the new custom

```cs
var customConverter = new JsonNetSerializer();
ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.JsonConverter = customConverter;
```

Use it, send your Json to NLog
`log.Info("Metadata: {@source}", metadata);`